# What is causing a string 'default value' in static mapping of a domain to cause an error when using HibernateDatastore in a test?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Updating tests in an application a string default value in the domain is causing an issue when creating a new HibernateDatastore. When trying to access the domain I get the error

***Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PERSON" not found;***

For some reason the table is not being built at all, but removing the string default value it will work.

Domain

```
@ToString(includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Person{
EnumType type = EnumType.Human
Long age = 10
String name = "StandardName"


static mapping = {
version false
type defaultValue: EnumType.Human
age defaultValue: 10
name defaultValue: "StandardName"
}

}
```

UnitTest

```
class PersonServiceSpec extends Specification implements DataTest, BuildDataTest {
    @Shared
    InterviewModelService interviewModelService

    @Shared
    HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore

    @Shared
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager


    def setupSpec() {
        mockDomain Person
        hibernateDatastore = new HibernateDatastore(Person)
        transactionManager = hibernateDatastore.getTransactionManager()
        interviewModelService = hibernateDatastore.getService(PersonService)
    }


    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    @Transactional
    void "test criteria builder for getting interview models"() {
        setup:
        Person.build(name: 'steve')

        when: 
        def x = Person.findAll()

        then: 
        x.size() == 3
    }




}
```

Comment: "Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PERSON" not found" - Does the `PERSON` table exist?  If not, do you have the `dbCreate` settings configured to create it when the session factory is initialized?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown if I remove name defaultValue: "StandardName" from the mapping the table will build, I am not getting any meaningful errors why it will not build, and only errors out once I try to use "Person"

Comment: @JeffScottBrown also allowing name to be an untyped variable def name = "StandardName" will allow it to be built

Comment: Untyping the variable is going to cause other problems.  You need static types on all of your persistent properties.

Comment: Why is it that you want to use `defaultValue` in the `mapping` block?

Comment: I didn't create the domain. So I am not sure. I didn't want to just remove it without understanding why it was causing the issue. But I don't think there is anything else in the application dependent on it, so removing it may be the easiest solution.